# Optimal Apache2 config for this scenario

Tags: apache-http-server, php

I'd be interested in hearing opinions on the best config for an Apache web server in this scenario.

I have a number of scripts (PHP) that run at regular intervals, the majority all at the same time, or the same timed intervals via a cron job.

As I put more an more of these scripts, called as webpages and written in PHP, I'm slightly concerned that I might start to 'lose' some of them on the way as they all trigger together.

As 'noone' actually sees them, nor waits for these pages to load (a delay of seconds isn't a problem) I was wondering what settings on apache2.conf to look at to make sure that all these pages calls are actually dealt with (even with a few seconds delay) rather than Apache throwing them away if it can't deal with them in a certain time period (as opposed to standard html/php pages that are being viewed by a person browsing the web server, these are just pages that execute scripts that no-one is really waiting for).

My ideal solution is that they (the pages being called via cron) just stack up and process one by one until the next batch are called or at a quieter period rather than apache killing them because they haven't executed in a particular time frame.

Of course I understand that if they queue for more time than the next batch are due to run then I have an issue.

On the same note, how can I view what apache has queued or pages that it is processing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see the need to use Apache in this context, if you have access to cron. You don't need to serve pages, apparently you only need to execute code.

Why not simply try something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

[Your code here.
 Perhaps even send e-mail updates 
 including with the status of your script,
 or update a lightweight database each time
 the script has run.]
```

Simple saving this script as /path/to/script.php, and calling `php /path/to/script.php` (or simply `./path/to/script.php` if you add execution rights to the file, using `chmod +x`) in your crontab, should do the job and save you a lot of Apache overhead.